# Creating View and Datatypes on redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Guessing this is straight forward but cant get it to run. The issue I am having is explicitly setting column data types in a view.

I need to do this as I will be unioning it to another table and need to match that tables datatypes.

Below is the code I have tried to run(I have tried without the sortkey aswell but still wont run)

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS testing.test_view;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW testing.test_view;
(
channel VARCHAR(80) ENCODE zstd,
trans_date TIMESTAMP ENCODE zstd
)
SORTKEY
(
       trans_date
)

AS

SELECT channel,
      trans_date

        from (
SELECT to_date(date,'DD-MM-YYYY') as trans_date,channel
FROM testing.plan
group by date,  channel
)
group by trans_date,channel;
```

The error message I am getting:

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command: CREATE OR REPLACE
>   VIEW trading.trading_squads_plan_v_test ( channel , trans_date  )
>
> AS
>
> SELECT channel VARCHAR(80) ENCODE zstd,
>         trans_date TIM...
>
> Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "VARCHAR" 
>   Position: 106;

Is this an issue with views where you cant set datatypes? If so is there a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: a table has data types and sort keys, a view does not.

Comment: Okay, thought that might be the case, using 0 place holders for a lot of the columns. I'll use a workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon pointed out my error was trying to set a datatype at the view level, which is not possible as its only pulling this from the table.

So I cast the values in the select call from the table:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS testing.test_view;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW testing.test_view;
(
channel,
trans_date,
source_region
)

AS

SELECT CAST(channel as varchar(80)),
       CAST(trans_date as timestamp),
       CAST(0 as varchar(80)) as source_region
        from (
SELECT to_date(date,'DD-MM-YYYY') as trans_date,channel
FROM testing.plan
group by date,  channel
)
group by trans_date,channel;
```